# Finding Maximal-Sum Positive Integer Subarray

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

You are given an integer array consisting of N positive integers. You have to pick a subarray of length K. Subarray means a contiguous part of an array. You need to find the sum of the subarray with the maximal sum among all such subarrays.

Input should be given as follows. On the first line, N and K: the size of the array, the size of the subarray to choose. On the next line: N integers, Ai.
The output should be the answer, the sum of the subarray that has the maximal sum.

Constraints
`1 ≤ K ≤ N ≤ 1000` and `1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000`

I solved it like this but 2 tests give errors. What have I overlooked?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(NULL);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int a,s[n],sum=0,ans=0,ans1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>a;
        sum+=a; 
        s[i]=sum;
    }
    if(k==n){
      cout<<sum<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--){
       if(i-k>=0){
         ans1=s[i]-s[i-k];
       }
         ans=max(ans,ans1);
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;}
```

https://algoleague.com/problem/max-subarray-2/detail

Comment: Here are some things you overlooked: `sync_with_stdio`, `using namespace std;`, variable length arrays, one statement per line and formatting your program has nothing to do with execution time.

Comment: You only print twice, so although printing is a known bottleneck, it shouldn't be a factor in the execution of your program.  Thus, there is little reason for `sync_with_stdio`.

Comment: To form a code block type ``` press enter paste the code exactly as it is in your IDE and press enter then type ``` again and press enter. No ` and ` at the beginning and end of each line.

Comment: Thomas Matthews,thanks but such things do not play a role in giving errors.  There is something wrong with the algorithm.thanks but such things do not play a role in giving errors of site.  There is something wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: Why do you need the `a[]` array?  In your `for` loop, you can replace with anothe variable like `b`, e.g. `{cin >> b; sum += b; s[i] = sum;}`  Which reminds me, use `braces` for sections with multiple statements and not the comma operator.  Again, adding braces does not significantly affect the compile time nor the execution time, but adds clarity and reduces probability of injecting defects.

Comment: What are the test cases that fail?  Have you used a debugger with those test cases?

Comment: I know the parts you said and the already written code, it just doesn't give me a time limit (wrong answer), so I don't consider such things at the initial stage

Comment: `int a[n]` is non-standard C++, so you might be advised here to use `std::vector`.

Comment: 'https://algoleague.com/problem/max-subarray-2/detail' it is link of problem.

Comment: You seem to have developed some really bad habits here: Declaring heaps of variables on the same line, needlessly stacking multiple statements with `,`, and eschewing proper indentation for the inner portion of loops like `for`. Your later `if` is also looking *extremely* ambiguous. Are you intending that both of those statements are conditional? They're indented that way, but they are *absolutely not* conditional that way.

Comment: I made some corrections

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Since you are "given an integer array consisting of N positive integers" the max subarray will always be the entire array.

Comment: he wants a subset of length k from me

Comment: @Isam Then just drop the minimum of the first and the last elements and you will have a strict subarray of size K where `K = N - 1`. I am quite sure that all the elements should not be positive.

Comment: @babon gives the number k in the input

Comment: @Isam Ahh... now we are talking... Use the "sliding window" approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an example that reproduces the issue, it is extremely difficult to debug an algorithm. You probably feel stuck because I presume the only feedback you got was that your submission failed a certain number of tests. As you might guess, that is also frustrating for someone trying to answer your question.

This is not a criticism of you trying to get help with your question, but a general commentary on the types of questions that appear from some programming competition sites which appear not to give sufficient feedback to encourage good debugging techniques.

Given that is the situation, here is an idea. I read your code and I cannot find any issues. I also tested it with some sample data I generated and it passed all the tests. Below, you will find a different implementation that uses a sliding window. Maybe by comparing the two strategies, you can try to figure out if there are actually any differences.

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int count, k;
    cin >> count >> k;

    int sum{};
    int arr[k];
    for (auto i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    int max_sum{sum};
    for (auto i = k; i < count; ++i) {
        auto idx = i % k;
        sum -= arr[idx];
        cin >> arr[idx];
        sum += arr[idx];
        max_sum = std::max(max_sum, sum);
    }

    cout << max_sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should get in the habit of using `std::vector`.  Arrays are for when the capacity is know at run-time (variable length arrays are not standard).  A `std::vector` can be used during runtime, when the capacity is not known at compile time.  Use `std::vector::push_back` to append values; let the `std::vector` manage the size.  Also, you can use the `size()` method to determine the capacity of the vector.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, I totally agree. The structure of these competition problems with strict bounds specified ahead of time encourages poor habits because you can get away with just declaring an array on the stack.